# embed javascript variable in asp.net control id

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I'm working with a table of asp.net controls on client side. They are all named in the following fashion when they are created on server side:  "txt_name_" + rowNum.  I know I can access them by their id by using "<%=Control.ClientID%>".  On client side I have access to current row num via a javascript variable.  I'm wondering how I can access one of the controls on client side by using something like the following(which doesn't seem to work): "<%=txt_name_" + jsRowNumVar + ".ClientID%>".  so I'm essentially trying to substitute a javascript variable as part of an asp.net control name and it doesn't seem to be working.  Any ideas on how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you can render your rows' client ids with an javascript array, and you can use it with the row index.

```
string jsToRender = "<script>var myCtrlIds = new Array('" + 
         text0.ClientId + "', '" + 
         text1.ClientId + "', '" + 
         text2.ClientId + "');</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(MyPage), "jsKey", jsToRender);
```

Then use the control id array in your client scripts :

```
<script>
      var text0Value = document.getElementById(myCtrlIds[0]).value;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like this the <% ... %> stuff is evaluated on the server and comes to the client as html. Placing the name of the javascript variable there will do no good for you